# Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts - cloning a Bitbucket repo via Git-Shell in Smartgit

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, smartgit, git-shell

I'm using ***Smartgit v7.1 on Windows 10***; I open the ***Git-shell*** in Smartgit and ran this command (***git fetch --all***) to clone a repo on Bitbucket server:

But I get the following error:

```
$ git fetch --all
Fetching origin
Could not create directory '/h/.ssh'.
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.domainName.net (00.00.000.00)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:POU+5KMU6lliH44u4J5fe7/WREtZZzrFamHLYqvql5g.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/h/.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
error: Could not fetch origin
```

I also tried running this command with no success:

```
$ ssh -vT git@bitbucket.domainName.net

OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.domainName.net [10.10.200.68] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
Could not create directory '/h/.ssh'.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /h/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version SSHD-CORE-0.14.1-ATLASSIAN-01
debug1: no match: SSHD-CORE-0.14.1-ATLASSIAN-01
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.domainName.net:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha2-256 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:HFU+5KVL6lliH44u4m5fe7/YAHtZZzrFamHLYqvql5g
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.domainName.net (10.10.200.68)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:HFU+5KVL6lliH44u4m5fe7/YAHtZZzrFamHLYqvql5g.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/h/.ssh/known_hosts).
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /h/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /h/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /h/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /h/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Anyone ran into this issue before on Windows 10 with Smartgit Git-Shell (
***I got to Git-Shell by opening SmartGit, then Tools > Open Git-Shell***)?

Answer (score 1):

By default, SmartGit will use its built-in SSH client which will only work when invoking commands directly from within SmartGit. The SSH client will not be available for externals tools, like the Git-Shell.

If you actually need to run remote commands from the Git-Shell, you have to configure Git's own SSH client.

Comment: Thanks for your response; instead of running that 'get fetch --all' from Git-Shell, I ended up doing a PULL on that repo from within SmartGit and somehow SmartGit was able to pull latest on that repo. I then switched to branch 'develop' and did another PULL on it. And that's how I was able to checkout repo via Smartgit, it just wouldn't work via the Git-Shell. And that's probably because of what you just explained mstrap; thanks